# xPath: Difficulties matching expression with actual source code

Tags: python, xml, selenium, xpath

From this [Deutsche Börse web page](http://en.boerse-frankfurt.de/etp/db-x-trackers-STOXX-GLOBAL-SELECT-DIVIDEND-100-UCITS-ETF-1D-LU0292096186), under the table header *Issuer* I want to get the string content `'db X-trackers'` in the cell next to the one with *Name* in it.

Using my web browser, I inspect that table area and get the code, which I've pasted into this XML tree just so that I can test my xPath.

```
<root>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <h2>Issuer</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Name</td>
                    <td class="text-right">db X-trackers</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</root>
```

According to [FreeFormatter.com](http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html#ad-output), my xPath below succeeds in retrieving the correct element (`Text='db X-trackers'`):

```
my_xpath = "//h2['Issuer']/ancestor::div[@class='row']/following-sibling::div//td['Name']/following-sibling::td[1]/text()"
```

*Note: It goes to `<h2>Issuer</h2>` first to identify the right place to start working from.*

---

However, when I run this on the actual web page using *Selenium WebDriver*, `None` is returned.

```
def get_sibling(driver, my_xpath):
    try:
        find_value = driver.find_element_by_xpath(my_xpath).text
    except NoSuchElementException:
        return None
    else:
        value = re.search(r"(.+)", find_value).group()
        return value
```

I don't believe anything is wrong in the function itself, so either the xPath must be faulty or there is something in the actual web page source code that throws it off.

When studying the actual *Source code* in Chrome, it looks a bit messier than what I see with *Inspector*, which is what I used to create the little XML tree above.

```
<div class="box">
                    <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <h2>Issuer</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
    <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table">
                    <tbody>
            <tr>
                    <td   >
                        Name
                    </td>
                    <td class="text-right"  >
                        db X-trackers
                    </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                    <td   >
                        Product Family
                    </td>
                    <td class="text-right"  >
                        db X-trackers
                    </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                    <td   >
                        Homepage
                    </td>
                    <td class="text-right"  >
                        <a target="_blank" href="http://www.etf.db.com">www.etf.db.com</a>
                    </td>
            </tr>
    </tbody>

            </table>
    </div>
```

Are there some peculiarities in the source code above, or is my xPath (or function) wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the [`following`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/following) and [`following-sibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/following-sibling) axis:

```
//h2[. = "Issuer"]/following::table//td[. = "Name"]/following-sibling::td
```

First we locate the `h2` element, then get the following `table` element. In the `table` element we look for the `td` element with `Name` text and then get the following `td` sibling.

Comment: Thanks so much for helping again! That xPath looks effective. Still getting a `None` result however. Very strange!

Comment: @Winterflags okay, quick check. How about `//h2[normalize-space(.) = "Issuer"]/following::table//td[normalize-space(.) = "Name"]/following-sibling::td`?

Comment: Works! `"Name"` needed to be normalized. Is it good practice to *always* do this?

Comment: Btw, there must have been a problem in my original xPath too because it doesn't work even if it's normalized.

Comment: @Winterflags yeah, you have to normalize it - there are extra newlines and could be extra spaces around the text..